# Advantage XPath Evaluation over XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xslt, xpath

I'm currently programming an application, that uses WPF.
Therefore I'm planning to load the GUI dynamically via XAML based upon a given XML.

As I see it, I have two choices:

1. Evaluate XML by myself with xpath and create GUI elements by myself.
2. Generate XAML through a XSLT transformation and load that file.

So, the question is, which way is more suitable? Or is there no difference and it's just a question of which way I prefer more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT sounds like a bad choice:**

1. As soon as things get a bit harder, you start hacking around, plus .NET framework uses XSLT version which is older than the last one. Meaning; you have a lot less capabilities available, unless you start using third-party library for XSL transformations.
2. Forcing developers to learn new technology which you can easily avoid. Imagine new developer taking over of your work with no experience on XSLT. I imagine the code will be even hard to read for experienced developers.

With XML, it's pretty straight forward. However, XPath can be also quite a mess, if you start nesting, and nesting.

Define a XML format, use xml-->object deserialization, and start building UI from the objects. Don't bother with `Xpath`. Use `XmlSerializer` for "parsing".

Comment: That's it! Now i use XmlSerializer to do the job. Works like a charm. :)